# Remove paragraph style with docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

In my word template file I have some tables and sometimes the second column of them is formatted as an enumeration.
Using docx4j I'm filling it with dynamic content and if there's only one entry I need to get rid of the enumeration style.
I found a place deep down in the structure that has a value for enumeration but when setting it to null, I don't see any changes in my template.

```
//This value is "Listenabsatz" (German) and I want to get rid of it
//Setting this value to "" or setting pStyle to null didn't help
((PStyle)((PPr)((P)((java.util.ArrayList)((Tc)((JAXBElement)templateRow.content.get(1)).value).content).get(0)).pPr).pStyle).val
```

In my actual code this is the place where I'm trying to change it:

```
Tr templateRow = (Tr) rows.get(0);
Tc cell = (Tc) ((javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) templateRow.getContent().get(1)).getValue();
P par = (P) (cell.getContent().get(0));
PPr parStyle = par.getPPr();
if (parStyle.getPStyle() != null && parStyle.getPStyle().getVal() != null) {
    parStyle.setPStyle(null);
    //parStyle.getPStyle().setVal("");
}
```

How can I remove that enumeration style succesfully?

Comment: parStyle.setPStyle(null) is fine.  Are you sure that code is being invoked?

Comment: @JasonPlutext thx for the reassurance, then I will concentrate on finding out where it might get lost on the way - so far while debugging it, it seemed to stay null until the very end